# MySQL SUM with SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have this table called `redeem_points`.
These are records where user redeemed points.

```
id  |userId |pointsCollected
-------------------------------
1    12      500
2    12      500
3    12      500
4    34      100
5    34      100
6    56      500
```

I want to generate a report, apart from these data I want to display an user's total points collected. like this

```
id  |userId |pointsCollected |totalPointsCollected
--------------------------------------------------
1    12      500             | 1500
2    12      500             | 1500
3    12      500             | 1500
4    34      100             | 200
5    34      100             | 200
6    56      500             | 500
```

How do I achieve this using MySQL?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can do

```
select t.*, t2.total
from your_table t
join 
(
  select userId, sum(pointsCollected) as total
  from your_table 
  group by userId
) t2 on t1.userId = t2.userId
```

but with MySQL 8+ you can simplify this to

```
select *, 
       sum(pointsCollected) OVER(PARTITION BY userId) AS total
from your_table
```